# Postsharp: Requested targeting pack NETStandard.Library.Ref not installed

Tags: c#, postsharp

I have a brand new Solution File containing a brand new .NET Core 3.1 console application. Whenever I add the [Discord.NET package](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net) to this project, PostSharp fails to compile with the following error:

Image containing the IDE error output

[image: Image containing the IDE error output]

```
Unhandled exception (PostSharp.Compiler.Hosting.CommandLine.dll 6.6.14 release | .NET Core 3.1.9 (X64)): Requested targeting pack NETStandard.Library.Ref, version=2.1.0 is not installed in C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\NETStandard.Library.Ref\2.1.0

PostSharp.Sdk.AssertionFailedException: Requested targeting pack NETStandard.Library.Ref, version=2.1.0 is not installed in C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\NETStandard.Library.Ref\2.1.0 ConsoleApp9 C:\Users\alexa\source\repos\ConsoleApp9\ConsoleApp9\POSTSHARP 

PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.PlatformContext.GetTargetingPack(KnownFrameworkReferenceInfo knownFrameworkReference) in C:\src\PostSharp-65\Public\Core\PostSharp.Compiler.Engine\Sdk\Extensibility\PlatformContext.cs:line 417 ConsoleApp9 C:\Users\alexa\source\repos\ConsoleApp9\ConsoleApp9\POSTSHARP
```

I have tried looking for the reference and I even tried installing it from the NuGet repository but it seems like some sort of SDK or internal package not meant to be consumed through the package manager. Does anyone know why Discord.NET is causing this issue or which targeting pack I need to get around this? Where does `NetStandard.Library.ref 2.1.0` come from?

I have the following SDKs installed:

```
2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.502 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.507 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.509 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.106 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-preview7-012821 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-preview8-013656 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-preview9-014004 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-rc1-014190 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.100-preview1-014459 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.100-preview2-014569 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.400-preview-015203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

And the following runtimes:

```
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

In `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\NetStandard.Library.Ref\` I have the following folders:

`2.1.0-preview7-27912-14`

`2.1.0-preview8-28405-07`

`2.1.0-preview9-19423-09`

Comment: I manually downloaded the NETStandard.Library.Ref 2.1.0 NuGet package and inserted it into `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\2.1.0` and the error has gone away. Does anyone know which SDK I'm supposed to get this pack from? I would like to make sure it's installed properly

Comment: This is going to be fixed in the next release of PostSharp 6.7, which is planned for the next week. In the meanwhile, installing the pack manually is a correct workaround.

Comment: Thank you @AntonínProcházka I know you all will get it fixed in no time. I'm just glad I was able to get PostSharp working so I can finish the trial. :)

Comment: This bug has been fixed in PostSharp 6.7.10.

Comment: Does Discord.NET use PostSharp? Or are you using PostSharp separately? I'm struggling to understand how these two dependencies are related.

Comment: @IanKemp Adding Discord to a project introduces a reference to a .NET Standard 2.1 assembly. This is what triggers the bug.

Comment: So the asker had a reference to PostSharp 6.6.14, added a ref to Discord.NET 2.2.0, and the fact that the latter references a NS 2.1 assembly triggered a bug in PostSharp - interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in PostSharp 6.7.10.

Answer (score 0):

What I did what download the .NET Standard Library Ref version 2.1.0 from NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library.Ref

I then unzipped the package and put it into a new folder called `2.1.0`, i.e. `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\NETStandard.Library.Ref\2.1.0`

The compile process works fine now.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in PostSharp 6.7.10.